# Ethereum2.0 Shard chains will be PoW or PoS

Tags: proof-of-stake, proof-of-work, eth-2.0, sharding

I'm sorry if this is a basic question. But will the new shard chains for Ethereum2.0 be PoW or PoS?

I know the plan is for Eth1 mainnet to "dock" onto the beacon chain eventually and be its own shard. But are all other new shards going to be PoS?

Answer (score 1):

Shard chains will use Proof-of-Stake (PoS) as a distributed consensus algorithm : a set of validators ("32 ETH stakers") will be pseudorandomly chosen by the beacon chain for each slot of each shard.

Comment: how do you know shard chains will be PoS? Is it documented somewhere? (I'll add the checkmark to your answer if you could supply that)

Comment: Very informative article here : https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain/ .

Comment: `At every epoch, a validator is pseudorandomly assigned to a slot and shard.  The validator is participating in the consensus of that assigned shard so that it can vote for that shard’s head.  The validator links the shard head to the beacon block for a slot.` Note the word `vote` which confirms the use of PoS for the shards.